# Can not cast IMAPInputStream to Multipart

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-mail, multipart

In Java project, I can receive mails from gmail server. But I want to receive the package part of body. And in this code sample my last `message(messages.length - 1)` is multipart/mixed.

Debug is pass on the `if` block but it fall into the catch block and gave me this message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart

How can I handle on this issue?

```
Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
        ArrayList<String> attachments = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            Part p = messages[i];
            if (messages[i].isMimeType("multipart/*")) 
            {           
                ***Multipart multipart = (Multipart) messages[i].getContent();***
                for (int j = 0, m = multipart.getCount(); j < m; j++) {

                    Part part = multipart.getBodyPart(j);
                    String disposition = part.getDisposition();
                    //
                    if (disposition != null
                            && (disposition.equals("ATTACHMENT"))) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(part.getFileName());
                        attachments.add(saveFile(MimeUtility.decodeText(part.getFileName()), part.getInputStream()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

### Edit

I fixed problem with using mail.jar, additional.jar and activation.jar which are using for only **Java Project**.

(I was download these jars before for my Android Project. That was the source of problem.)

Answer (score 12):

I ran into similar problem while I was to read message attachments using Android JavaMail. I have fixed this error by adding following lines of code. There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. This resolved my problem. Hope it helps someone out there.

```
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
```

Cheers!

Comment: this worked for me. Incidentally, my packaging program had thrown these warnings: [warn] Merging 'META-INF/mailcap' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/mailcap.default' with strategy 'discard'
which probably meant that it ignored some useful things from the javax library..

Comment: @RahulUpadhyay Just add these lines of code to your java class where your are trying to init email lib.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because JAF can't find the configuration file that maps MIME types to classes.  The most common reason for that failure is that the environment you're running in isn't setting the thread's context class loader correctly.  See [this JavaMail forum thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2369993&tstart=0) for a workaround.

The second most common reason for this failure is that you repackaged the classes in the mail.jar file into your own jar file, but forgot to include the configuration files in the META-INF directory.

Comment: But I am not using Tomcat , it is just a console application

Comment: Maybe I should ask the main problem. My aim is receiving the image from mail body. How can I do that with Java. I mean my code is looking ok for this problem?

Comment: at this question http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/javamail-interest@java.sun.com/msg00073.html. I can receive all the image like him. Can I show it like the normal image ? This is exactly what I want to do

Comment: You're just running your program from the command line using the "java" command?  Try running the msgshow.java demo program that comes with JavaMail.  If that doesn't work, explain more about your environment.  What JDK version are you using on what operating system?

Comment: I fixed it. My libraries were for Android Development. I realized that and I download the jars for Java Development. And then I can download the image into my computer. Actually, I am doing this Java Project for understanding the download any image. Because my real aim is download an image into the Android SD Card. By the way I said I can download the image into the my computer but my mail's package name is "xx.jpg" but the downloaded one into my computer name is "xx.jpg0" If I fix the jpg0 to jpg, then I can see my image. How can I download the image directly xx.jpg. What is wrong with this?

Comment: No idea.  What code are you using to download the image?  Is it coming as an attachment to an email message?  Note that the filename used with an email attachment can be anything and you shouldn't trust it.

Comment: I fixed it too with another code sample. I will edit the code under my question. But actually now I was trying to fix another problem.. I am trying to access my account with my code but I am getting error : "Host is unresolved : imap.gmail.com" Sometimes I got this error because of Imap doesnt gave any service at that time. Because of this reason I want to access my mails with Pop but I couldnt. I am trying it over a hour. If I open another question could you tell me what should I do, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I asked there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324379/cant-receive-mails-with-pop-in-android

Comment: your suggested link is not working. Showing page not found. @BillShannon

Answer (score 0):

just curious, the type architecture shows they are from the different super class:

public class IMAPInputStream extends java.io.InputStream {}

public abstract class Multipart {}

protected synchronized void Multipart::setMultipartDataSource(MultipartDataSource mp);

while MultipartDataSource is defined as javax.mail.MultipartDataSource.