# Unable to import javax.activation in Jdeveloper for MAF

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, jdeveloper, multipart, oracle-maf

I am trying to deploy an Oracle MAF app to the iOS platform. I am using Java Mail to receive emails from the gmail server. I am trying to to identify mails that have attachments. However I get the following error.

**java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart**

When I identify the mime type of the message as "multipart/mixed", I am trying to cast the object into Multipart.

I understand that this question has been asked before but I have tried to implement the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302564/can-not-cast-imapinputstream-to-multipart).
 However I am unable to import anything from javax.activation. The error that I get in jdeveloper is

**Error : javax.activation.CommandMap is not available in the profile.**

This error shows up for everything from javax.activation

Also, this error pops up only in an MAF application. It works well in a normal java project.

How can I handle this issue?

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class Email {
    public Email() 
    {

        String userName = "abc@gmail.com";
        String password = "password";
        String receivingHost;

        receivingHost="imap.gmail.com";

        Properties props=System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

        Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        try 
        {
             Store store=session.getStore("imaps");
             store.connect(receivingHost,userName, password);
             Folder folder=store.getFolder("INBOX");
             folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
             Message messages[]=folder.getMessages();

             //System.out.println(messages.length);
             for (Message message : messages) 
             {
                 if(message.isMimeType("multipart/mixed")) 
                 {
                     Multipart mp = (Multipart)message.getContent();
                     //get content    
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                    //getcontent
                 }
             }

             store.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        //System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you including JavaMail in your application?  Are you including the JavaMail jar file or are you extracting the classes from the jar file and just including the classes?  The latter won't work unless you also include the config files in META-INF.  I don't know why JDeveloper won't let you import javax.activation; what version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: @BillShannon Thanks for the response. I am importing the java mail jar and the activation jar  using the project properties->Libraries and classpath. I am using JDK 8

Comment: I really don't know anything about JDeveloper but javax.activation is part of JDK 8 so if it won't let you import it without doing anything special, JDeveloper is broken and you should file a bug against it.

Comment: Importing the jar file probably tells JDeveloper to package it in your application (the common case) so you need to find a way to tell it to use the jar file for compiling but **not** package it with your application.  Maybe if you can just tell it that you're developing a Java EE application it will handle this for you?